# Can the FlexIO module in NXP be used as I2C?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, i2c, nxp

I have this [S32K142](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/S32K-DS.pdf) microcontroller. Unfortunately, it has only one I2C interface which I have already used.

I require another I2C interface for a different light sensor application - [light sensor](https://www.vishay.com/docs/84366/veml6030.pdf).

I read this [Flex IQ note](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/supporting-information/FTF-ACC-F1179_Introduction_to_FlexIO.pdf) which mentions that the Flex IO pins can be used as an I2C module independently.

So, I read the reference manual and found the ports which will support FLEX IO and found the below :

[image]

I found that the ports PTD2 and PTD3 ports would support Flex IO. So, can I connect these 2 pins (PTD2 and PTD3) to an I2C communication device? Please confirm.

Comment: I'm not motivated to read the datasheet, but in most cases you can bit-bash I2C using gpio and a few lines of code.

Comment: not much action on your other question yesterday. You might want to bring that to a conclusion.

Comment: You do know that you're not limited to a single I2C peripheral on an I2C bus don't you? Why do you feel that you need to dedicate an individual I2C port on your micro to the light sensor?